# Why does vector<T>::emplace_back, such that T has a deleted copy constructor, fail to compile?

Tags: c++, back, emplace

I cannot compile the following `dont_compile` function. I don't understand why it doesn't work. But, it does work with `list`.

```
class Thing {
public:
    Thing() {}
    Thing(const Thing &) = delete;
};

int dont_compile(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::vector<Thing> v;
    v.emplace_back();

    return 0;
}

int compiles(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::list<Thing> v;
    v.emplace_back();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error from the compiler. Is it a bug?

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1752:31: error: call to deleted constructor of 'Thing'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

... snip ...

note: 'Thing' has been explicitly marked deleted here
        Thing(const Thing &) = delete;
```

I don't really understand how `_Up(...)` is causing the copy constructor to be invoked.

Comment: What do you think is going to happen if `std::vector` needs to allocate a new buffer as its capacity grows?

Comment: I assumed it would use the default move constructor, but it turns out it was deleted automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works when you have move constructor:

```
#include <vector>

class Thing {
public:
    Thing() {}
    Thing(const Thing &) = delete;
    Thing(Thing&&) = default;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Thing> v;
    v.emplace_back();
    return 0;
}
```

The type requirements of [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) can provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually already tried to add a move constructor but it didn't work because I had a slightly more complex situation where there was a sub-object that wasn't movable, and so it seems like the default move constructor wasn't available for `std::vector`. I'll have to test some more but now I know that this should work, that's very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector::emplace_back` requires the type of the vector to be `EmplaceConstructible` as well as `MoveInsertable`. Since you delete the copy constructor and do not define a move constructor yourself, `Thing` does not satisfy the second requirement. In contrast, `std::list::emplace_back` only requires the list type to be `EmplaceConstructible`.